# Collector to join incoming lists

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a method that receives a collector. The collector should combine incoming lists:

```
reducing(Lists.newArrayList(), (container, list) -> {
   container.addAll(list);
   return container;
})
```

This seems like a very common scenario to me, and I believe Java's own collector should have something to cover this use case, but I cannot remember what. Besides, I want it to return `ImmutableList`.

Comment: Java 9 introduced Collectors.flatMapping : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Comment: Can you use _`Collections.unmodifiableList(List<T>)`_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain a "flattened" list of elements from a nested collection firstly you need to apply [**`flatMapping()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) which takes a **function** that turns an *element* to a *stream* and a **collector** as second argument. And to get an immutable list apply [**`toUnmodifiableList()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList()) as a **downstream collector** inside the `flatMapping()` (*as already mentioned by [racraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681444/racraman) and [hfontanez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851311/hfontanez) in their comments, since they pointed that earlier the credits for this answer should belong to them*).

```
    List<List<Integer>> nestedList = List.of(
            List.of(1, 2),
            List.of(3, 4)
    );

    nestedList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.flatMapping(List::stream,
                        Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**output**

```
1
2
3
4
```

---

A more **common use-case** for `Collector.flatMapping()` is when each element of the stream holds a *reference to a collection*, rather than being a *collection* itself.

Consider the following scenario.

We have a *collection* of `Order`s. Each `Order` has an *id* and a *collection* of `Item`s. And we want to obtain a **map** from this *collection of orders* so that based on the *order id* we can get a *list of items*.

In this situation `Collector.flatMapping()` is indispensable because by applying the `flatMap()` in the middle of the stream we will lose access to the `orderId` in the `collect()`. Hence, flattening should happen inside the `collect()` operation.

A method that implements the logic described above might look this:

```
public Map<String, List<Item>> getItemsByOrderId(Collection<Order> orders) {
    return orders.stream()
            // some logic here
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getId,
                     Collectors.flatMapping(order ->
                                     order.getItems().stream().filter(somePredicate),
                             Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do `flatMap()` operation and `toList()` collector, to collect multiple incoming lists to one resultant list.

```
List<String> joinedList = Stream.of(
   asList("1", "2"),
   asList("3", "4")).flatMap(list -> list.stream()
)
.collect(toList());

System.out.println("Printing the list named as joinedList: " + joinedList);
```

**Output:**

```
Printing the list named joinedList: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```